# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

```
line="101 : johnny 'wave-boy' jones:usa:8.32:fish:21"
s={}
(identity,name,country,average,boardtype,age)=line.split()
print(identity)
```

My output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    (identity,name,country,average,boardtype,age)=line.split()
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack
```

Comment: `(expected 2)` - really? Are you sure that's the code you're running - you wouldn't get that message...

Answer (score 3):

`line.split()` returns `['101', ':', 'johnny', "'wave-boy'", 'jones:usa:8.32:fish:21']`

It has a length of 5, while you are unpacking it a to a tuple that has 6 elements.

When you split a string without passing parameters, the method behaves as `string.split(' ')`

I think that what you want to achieve can be reached with `line.split(':')`

Answer (score 3):

You're splitting the line at whitespace characters. I suppose you want to split it at colons, which you could achieve by

```
identity, name, country, average, boardtype, age = line.split(':')
```

Answer (score 2):

when you split `line`, you get a list of 5 values, and you are trying to assign it to 6 values

ie,

```
>>> line="101 : johnny 'wave-boy' jones:usa:8.32:fish:21"
>>> line.split()
['101', ':', 'johnny', "'wave-boy'", 'jones:usa:8.32:fish:21']
>>> (a,b,c,d,e) = line.split()
>>> (a,b,c,d,e,f) = line.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is happening when you `split()` your string:

```
>>> line="101 : johny 'wave-boy' jones:usa:8.32:fish:21"
>>> line.split()
['101', ':', 'johny', "'wave-boy'", 'jones:usa:8.32:fish:21']
>>> len(line.split())
5
```

yet you are asking for a 6-tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use a colon (`':'`) as the delimiter for `split`. When you call `split` without any arguments, it defaults to whitespace as the delimiter.